# Java serialize List<object> each object holds a file in a byte array

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, arrays, fileinputstream

I have an object that has a List each ObjectA has a few data members (strings and a byte[]). Along with a FileInputStream used to read a file into the byte array. I have initialized all data members in the global scope of the object so that I can recycle them to reduce the amount of object creation per function call. When I serialize the object my FileInputStream is null, as I store the file in the byte array. so I expect that the FileInputStream being null would be skipped by the serialization process. both the main object and the objects that are put in the list of the main object are implementing serializable

I'm able to serialize the object that holds the list of objects and deserialize it as long as the list is empty. When the list has at least one object in it. It's still able to serialize but when i attempt to deserialize it I get the following error.

```
IOException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileInputStream
```

The variables in my object's is as followed:

```
public class MainObject implements Serializable{
     private String name;
     private List<ObjectA> obj;
}

public class ObjectA implements Serializable{
         private String id;
         private String name;
         private File fileStream;
         byte []data;
}
```

To trouble shoot this I saved the serialized object to a file and looked at it and I can see the MainObject is being saved. If I include objects into the list the objects are also being saved.

Here is the code I made for reading the files and adding them to the object.

```
   File[] files = new File(filePath).listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(filePath+file.getName());
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                mainObjectList.add((MainObject) ois.readObject());
                ois.close();
                fin.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }   
        }
    }
```

here is the setFile() that's in MainObject

```
   public void setFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            File file=null;
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(file=new File(filePath));
            data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileStream.read(data,0,data.length);
            for (int X : data){
                System.out.print((char)X);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Define 'an object', 'not able', etc. It certainly has nothing to to do with the byte[].

Comment: Try again. Fail how? Exception? Stack trace? Computer explodes? Supernova? NB `fileStream` is a poorly chosen name for an object of type `File.`

Comment: The exception you have just edited into your answer proves that the code you have posted in your answer isn't the real code, as there is no `FileInputStream` anywhere in evidence there. As does the `audioClip/AudioClip` typo. And I asked for a stack trace.

Comment: I'm leaving out setters and getters. as they would just add unneeded length at this time. I believe the problem is with the Byte array but i can't be certain. All other objects i have serialized work with no problem but the first one with a byte array holding byte code from a wave file has problems so process of elimination i believe it has to do with the byte array.

Comment: @PatrickWMcMahon Please read what I wrote again. It is impossible for this code to throw the exception you posted. *Ergo* either that isn't the real code or that isn't the real exception. Please post code that exhibits the problem, unless you want the question to be closed as incomplete or non-reproducible. NB There is precisely zero evidence for your guesswork about the `byte[]` array.

Comment: EJP what are you talking about. look at `File[] files = new File(filePath).listFiles();` that is getting the file.

Comment: @PatrickWMcMahon Please read what I wrote *again.* What I am talking about is the fact that the exception mentions `FileInputStream,` which is not present in any of your code. It is also now evident from your stack trace that there was an exception when *writing* this data, which you have ignored.

Comment: the object AudioClip has a FileInputStream but thats just used to bring the wave file in the file is then stored in the byte[]. why would the FileInputeStream object be doing anything? Im only using it for the setter for the wave file.

Comment: There is finally enough here to answer the question. Next time please make sure that you post a reproducible problem, and enough information about the actual problem to allow a diagnosis and solution.

Comment: Sorry i didn't want to clutter the question with getters and setters unless needed.

Comment: @PatrickWMcMahon I don't care about the getters and setters. I care about the missing `FileInputStream` member whose existence I have had to drag out of you, along with the error message, and the stack trace. It's like pulling teeth. This should not have taken an hour and several requests. It should all have been there in the first place.

Comment: At the time i was not getting an error message my try{}catch did not have `e.printStackTrace();` at the time. It was only after you responded i realized why i was not getting errors. due to the fact that i was not getting errors i had no idea the problem was with the FileInputStream so i didn't think to mention it. Please remove the -3 points you guys put on my question. I fixed it and it now has all the information.

Comment: I was working all day on the program and at the time of writing up the question i had more then a full days work on the project. So i'm sorry if it took a little long with the question. I was trying to keep the question short and relevant. Please remove the -6 points that was put on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the exception message. Contrary to the code you posted, you have a `FileInputStream` member, which is not serializable. Make it transient, or remove it, and construct it when you need it from the `File`.

And contrary to your claim that 'When i serialize mainObject and save it to a file i can see its saving all the data including the list of audioClip objects', when you serialized this data you got an exception, which you have ignored.

NB Your newly posted code:

```
try {
        File file=null;
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(file=new File(filePath));
        data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        fileStream.read(data,0,data.length);
        for (int X : data){
            System.out.print((char)X);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

is very poor quality. It should have been written like this:

```
try (FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))) {
    data = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    int total = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = fileStream.read(data, total, data.length-total)) > 0) {
        total += count;
    }
    for (byte X : data) {
        System.out.print((char)X);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that you cannot assume either that a file fits into memory, that the size fits into an `int,` or that `read()` fills the buffer. You have to:

- store the result of `read()` into a variable
- test it for -1, indicating end of stream
- otherwise use it as the read count, instead of the buffer size
- repeat until end of stream.

Note also that you don't need the `File file` variable at all; that the `FileInputStream` should always have been a local variable; and that you weren't closing it: this code does, via the try-with-resources syntax.

Comment: I moved the FileInputStream from the global scope of the object to the local scope of the setter and now it works. Looks like it serializes all global objects to the serializable object even when not being used.

Comment: @PatrickWMcMahon It serializes all non-transient non-static data members. That is Java Object Serialization 101. If it's only used as a local variable it shouldn't have been a data member anyway.

Comment: so all setters and getters should be static as well so not to add to the file, correct?

Comment: @PatrickWMcMahon Please read what I wrote, ***again.*** I said *'data members'.* Getters and setters are not data, and they are not serialized. Your question doesn't even make sense. Getters and setters for instance data members cannot be static in the first place.

Comment: After looking at your code changes I think you made a mistake. From what I see your while loop only runs one time and is basically doing nothing. Your code is doing exactly the same thing. The total is set to 0 at the start of the loop. so when you do data.length-total your setting it to data.length-0 so you don't need the white loop as your only running the read() one time.

Comment: I have a few questions about your suggested code. where are you getting the 'file' object from on line 2. Why are you using a while loop on line 5 when your only passing one file stream. I don't understand why your counting a total that looks to not be used for anything. Is your while loop overwriting the data variable every time it runs if so are you getting the full file. This looks like it would run the while loop and then overweight the data from the first file attempt.